# Catalina.sh when opened using vi editor , is showing ^@ for each character in each line

Tags: tomcat, catalina

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z7Roi.jpg)Catalina.sh when opened using vi editor , is showing ^@ for each character in each line. How to make it readable.

Comment: It isn't readable, it is corrupt. Off topic.

Comment: so what to do . download a latest apache and put the application in it